# Vaadin 7 crop image

Tags: java, jquery, vaadin7

I'm looking for some vaadin component to select part of image and crop it. Surprisely I've found nothing for Vaadin 7 however I can implement image crop using javascript and jQuery. Maybe some one know existing crop component for Vaadin 7? Or how can I embed my own clint side crop?

Comment: Is it working for you ?

Comment: I am also looking for same thing.If you have solution pls share with me..

Comment: I just took jCrop js library (http://jcrop.org/) and created custom Vaadin component based on it

Comment: Can u pls share code for that vaadin component if possible.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not working in company where I wrote this code anymore so I don't have access to the code. Take a look on https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

There is addon for that: [Cro Field Addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/cropfield:vaadin) 
Unfortunately, it's works only with Vaadin 6, but source code is available.

Vaadin 7 have good JavaScript integration. Maybe you can use one of the js libraries to do this task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've managed to write my own js component to do the job. Maybe I'll wrap it as a plugin if I'll have time